# Automated software hackers use to try passwords

Tags: passwords, authentication, email, password-management

Because of the eBay hacking, I had to go and look for other accounts that I have used the same password to change the passwords on those site as well. (I know that it's very bad to have same passwords across multiple sites to begin with....but it was already done) I unfortunately don't know if I was able to find all the sites that I used that specific password. I read that once hackers get one password, they use some automated software and try the same password, with same login details on bunch of other sites/accounts.

Where can I get a list of common sites that hackers try to automate login using passwords they stole?

Also, do you have any tips on how I can try to find as many sites that I used the same password as possible? I already tried the ones I use a lot.

Thank you in advance. Since only my name and address were potentially taken, I don't have any need for worry, right?

Comment: I would venture to get the most common sites are also the ones that most people use a lot, so you could start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_websites.  I also wouldn't worry too much about sites you don't use too much unless they have private data like SSN or credit card numbers.  I also don't believe name and address is that big of a deal since for a lot of people it is common knowledge via a phone book.

Comment: @TravisPessetto there were couple of internship applications I had to make which required me to give personal information, and possibly SSN, for which I had to make accounts; it's possible I used the same password for those as my previous eBay password; Should I be worried about those? There were too many too many applications for me to remember them all.

Comment: Yes, those could be a cause of worry especially if they use a common application provider.  You could hope that the employer didn't store your whole SSN, just the last four, but it is impossible to say if they did or didn't without knowing how they coded it.  If you are a US citizen I would advise you to keep watch over your credit using something like creditkarma.com to make sure nobody is using your SSN in malicious ways also it is wise to get taxes done as soon as possible in the year to avoid people using it to get your tax return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off, you seem to have 2 questions, a list of common sites, and if you should be worried.

To the first one, that's a hard one, there are millions of websites around the world, and a couple of thousands are considered to be "used a lot", so getting a list of the most hit sites is hard, and even if you find one, it's a huge one.

I'd suggest changing the passwords of every site you use. The BEST thing to do is to have different and strong passwords for every site (I am lazy and have passwords like P@s$w0rd100, P@s$w0rd101, etc.), so maybe that's an idea.

To the second question: yes and no, this really depends on what kind of information was present, and what the hackers obtained. If they obtained credit card information, it's best to go to the bank NOW and block them, get a new one, etc.

Any address information wouldn't matter, since they would have addresses and names of thousands of people, why would they even need your address?

And if you're an US citizen, I think it's possible they have your SSN and Name combination too. I'd suggest keeping a CLOSE EYE on any malicious activity on there, in fact, always keep a close eye on anything related to your money, SSN, etc.

Comment: Please don't use the "lazy" approach recommended. Use a password manager and solve the problem for real. LastPass, KeePass, 1Password, etc., are all well-built implementations. Pick one, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple factors authentication, there are many options. Yubikey is the simplest - http://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/yubikey/

And there're a lot of similar devices, just look for "authentication token"

There's even a more strict approach which is if you want to secure your password - don't use it at all. like this http://www.wwpass.com/resources/passkey

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an answer to the question at all. The OP is asking about finding websites he uses, you are talking about MFA.